# How to retrieve api key for IBM containers after first usage

Tags: ibm-cloud

the api key, used in 'ice login -k xxx', was shown when I started to use IBM containers beta. After that, where can I retrieve my api key in case I forgot it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'ice login' does not require -k option any more. If unauthorized error is shown after 'ice login', delete lines 'x_auth_token' and 'api_key' from ~/.ice/ice-cfg.ini, and try 'ice login' again, everything should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the latest version of the cli you just need to type `ice login` and it will log you into to the Containers Service.  The cli with authenticate you with your Bluemix username and password.

To check what version of the CLI you have installed type the following.

```
[09:18 PM]>pip list | grep icecli
icecli (2.0)
```

As of this writing the latest version is 2.0.

The latest installer as of this writing can be fetched from https://static-ice.ng.bluemix.net/icecli-2.0.zip.

Comment: Thanks, but ice login seems log me into CF only.
<pre>
    $ ice login
    API endpoint: https://api.ng.bluemix.net
    
    Email> xxxxx@jp.ibm.com
    
    Password> 
    Authenticating...
    OK
    ...
    $ ice ps
    Command failed with container cloud service
    Unauthorized failure
</pre>

Comment: Do you have access to the container beta?

Comment: Sorry I did not know stackoverflow does not allow code block in comment...
'ice login' without -k option seems log me into CF only.
After 'ice login' ends successfully, 'ice ps' still reports 'Unauthorized failure'. My 'ice version' shows 2.0 and I am using ubutnu 14.04LTS.

Comment: Jeff, yes IBM contaner beta is enabled on my account, and I can create my docker containers now.

Comment: Sometimes that can happen if docker is not setup correctly on your local machine, does docker work locally?

Comment: Jeff, yes docker itself works fine. Well, can I check my api key in Bluemix dashbord screen (in web browser)? I cannot find it.

Comment: The login has changed, you need to login with your CF credentials, that will authenticate you with the container service.

Comment: I have re-installed cf tools. But still cannot login... The version I am using is: Python=2.7.6, cf=6.11.3-cebadc9-2015-05-20T19:00:58+00:00, ice=2.0. 'ice ps' after 'ice login' succeeded says 'Unauthorized failure'. I noticed one wired message when I invoke 'ice info': 'Sorry, an error occurred on our side: 'str' object does not support item assignment [Incident ID 1a67c4fd875d560b]'.

Comment: I noticed that when I delete lines 'x_auth_token' and 'api_key' from ~/.ice/ice-cfg.ini, and try 'ice login' again, everything works fine!